# Deleting Particle Settings Data Blocks

Tags: data-blocks

I wanted to be straight. I just wanted to delete this data-blocks, because leaving it unbaked in my scene is eating a lots of ram. I've set an example:

[image]

So many of them were unused and just a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I was just searching for an answer to the same question. If the particle system is unused by any object Blender will delete it on quit. However sometimes in complex scenes it can be hard to find the object that has the particle system.

You can remove it in the Outliner workspace by selecting Blender File  to display file data and linked libraries, under Particles you will see all your Particle systems and you can Right click and delete them.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the thread [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/removing-particle-system-settings/491840), these particle settings data-blocks should be automatically cleared upon restarting blender.

Can you try quitting and reopening blender and seeing if they have been removed?